# Help Identifying This Part

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am trying to identify an IC which is marked as follows:

```
20071
B1400
```

It is a 10 pin IC. It is a photoflash capacitor charging IC. It likely has an IGBT driver integrated as well. I've had no luck with google (I have in the past) and I don't know where else to search with this limited information. The IC measures 2.5mm x 2.0mm (~.080"x.100").

[image: Photo of unidentified IC]

**EDIT:**

I have found that this particular part is used in many cameras according to this [site](http://photo-parts.com.ua/parts/dbphp.php?part=20071). Seems it is quite common...

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words - if you're good with closeups (lighting challenges, focus problems, etc.  It's not straightforward).

Comment: Not the best photo... I'll see if I can do better.

Comment: Can you measure the size of the chip to figure out what package it is? The more info the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After roughly 20 hours of detective work I have found my part! It is made by Renesas of all companies. The part number is R2J20071BNS. Now, I have found the part but I can't find the datasheet. The only part information I have to go on is in a [product guide](http://documentation.renesas.com/doc/products/linear/r18cs0003ej0200_standardic.pdf) (page 13) published by Renesas. However, the product guide identifies the pins I am interested in (FULL and FLSW).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found the part you mentioned (yet). But I'll offer some resources you may or may not have looked at already.

Based on what you've told and shown us, we're looking for a 10-pin chip, in a surface mount package with leads, that is a photoflash capacitor charger with IGBT driver. The following sites turn up with several chips that fit this description:

[Digikey](http://www.digikey.com)
[Mouser](http://www.mouser.com)
[FindChips](http://www.findchips.com)

I don't think there's a way to link directly to the search results. I began by searching for "photoflash" or "photo-flash" and filtered the results based on the description.

I've looked through a handful of the Digikey results and haven't come up with any matches based on manufacturer part number. That's not to say one of the results isn't your chip. It's isn't unheard of that chip markings on smaller chips don't match their part number. I'd suggest looking through the datasheets and see if any of them mention their markings. Some of the manufacturers include some of the usual suspects: Texas Instruments, Maxim, Linear Technology, and Allegro Microsystems.

Good luck!

EDIT:

I still haven't come up with anything, but I was thinking about it a bit more. I hope I haven't led you astray, but I was wondering whether the chip actually has leads. The picture is small and a bit blurry (understandable), so it's a little difficult to judge. I bring this up partly because of the dimensions you added. There doesn't seem to be a 10-pin package with leads that is that small. Most of what I saw were 10-MSOP, which seem to typically be 3mm x 3mm. However, there are some DFN packages that are smaller and at least get the ratio correct, i.e. 3mm x 2mm. You may want to peruse any parts without leads that you (and I) may have discounted earlier.

Lastly, if you're desperate for more info, and confident in your soldering skills, you might consider removing the chip completely. There doesn't appear to be any silkscreen on the board, but the underside of the chip itself may reveal either an exposed pad or more text.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @bjthom for taking the time! I've found that the number marked on the package is usually NOT the part number. I assume this is due to limited real estate. I have been successful in the past IF I know the general function of the IC and the part marking. This time I am out of luck. However, I didn't even think about Allegro so I am investigating that now.

Comment: In response to your edit, no, there are no leads on these packages. I found lots of Allegro parts which are 10 pin DFN packages but Allegro does not provide part marking in the datasheet (or I am overlooking it more likely). However, I am fairly confident the parts are not Allegro just by the pinout alone (control pins connected to transformer primary, etc.).